# How do I delete/truncate records in a table before applying inserts in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to copy the contents of a JSON data source to an SQL table (completely replacing what is already there) and everything works except I cannot figure out how to delete the existing contents in the SQL table before applying the INSERTs from the data source.

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4522 'Add "SQL Statement" property to PutSQL' I should be able to define a "DELETE FROM mytable;" SQL Statement in a PutSQL processor and that should execute the statement instead of the incoming flow file and then pass the original flow file on to the next step. But I am getting a PostgreSQL invalid column index error.

The NiFi version is 1.21.0. The SQL database I'm writing to is PostgreSQL 14.

My arrangement is:

1. RunMongoAggregation (fetches JSON) -> 'results'
2. ConvertJSONToSQL (creates INSERT statements) -> 'sql'
3. PutSQL-1 (has "SQL Statement" defined with "DELETE FROM mytable;") -> 'success'
4. PutSQL-2 (executes INSERT statements)

Properties in PutSQL-1:

- JDBC Connection Pool: DBCPConnectionPool
- SQL Statement: "delete from mytable;"
- Support Fragemented Transations: false
- Database Session AutoCommit: false
- Transaction Timeout: (empty)
- Batch Size: 100
- Obtain Generated Keys: false
- Rollback On Failure: true

My problem is that the "PutSQL-1" step fails with:

```
PSQLException: The column index is out of range 2; number of columns 0.
```

If I remove the "PutSQL-1" step and route the 'sql' from ConvertJSONtoSQL to PutSQL-2 directly everything works perfectly; except I have to manually delete all existing records beforehand!

Do I have the wrong approach? Or is this a NiFi issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE` if you want to remove the whole data from the table, as its performant.

[image: Sampleflow]

I tried to replicate your flow, `ConvertJSONToSQL` gives you output SQL statements. In the sample flow that's replaced with a `GenerateFlowfile` with an Insert statement.

Second step is the `PutSQL` is setup with the `TRUNCATE` statement

[image: PutSQL]

On success the output of the processor is the `INSERT` statement that was generated from the `GenerateFlowfile` which is then passed on to the second `PutSQL`

Comment: Thank you DataWrangler, I replaced the DELETE with TRUNCATE TABLE and configured the PutSQL processor exactly like yours but unfortunately I still get the same error message.

Comment: I also downgraded to release 1.20.0 and tried again but still the same results

Comment: That's strange, can you try this please. 

Make a new flow, as I have shown above, with the `GenerateFlow` which has the insert statement that is passed to the `PutSQL` and then see if the issue still persists.

Comment: That worked perfectly straight away; shouldn't the PutSQL processor not pass on the source FlowFile to the next processor if "SQL Statement" is set, independent of where it comes from?

Comment: Yup, it does which is why the sample flow for me and you worked. Bit strange why it doesn't work for your usecase with the `ConvertJSONToSQL`